# Viewing / Reloading emacs backup files

Tags: emacs, backup

I am successfully using the code below to cause emacs to save many versions of each file.  But I cannot figure out what commands you use in emacs to actually load those files into a buffer.

I am expecting some kind of a history viewer command!!!  I can find nothing.

```
(setq backup-directory-alist  '(("." . "~/auto-saves")))
(setq version-control     t
    kept-old-versions   2    kept-new-versions  200
    delete-old-versions t    backup-by-copying  t)
```

Comment: Have you tried `M-x recover-file` or does this not do what you want?

Comment: Elethan, I believe the "recover" series of commands will retrieve from the auto-save file.  (This is the file that has a "~" at the end by default).  Emacs also saves multiple previous versions of your files if you turn on BACKUPS.  These files are different.  and there seems to be no command to retrieve those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just open the files in which ever directory you're saving them in (`~/autosaves`).  But the [backup-walker](https://github.com/lewang/backup-walker) package is way better.

---

Update: I highly recommend using the `no-littering` package to keep your `~/.emacs.d` (and `$HOME`) clean.  Here's my backup config (assuming you have `use-package` and melpa set up):

```
(use-package no-littering)

(setq make-backup-files t
      vc-make-backup-files t
      version-control t
      kept-new-versions 128
      kept-old-versions 0
      delete-old-versions t
      backup-by-copying t)

(defun force-backup-of-buffer ()
  (setq buffer-backed-up nil))
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'force-backup-of-buffer)

(use-package backup-walker)

(let ((dir (no-littering-expand-var-file-name "auto-save/")))
  (make-directory dir t)
  (add-to-list 'auto-save-file-name-transforms `(".*" ,dir t) 'append))
```

If you don't want to use `no-littering`, set `backup-directory-alist`, `tramp-persistency-file-name`, `tramp-backup-directory-alist`, and `tramp-auto-save-directory`.

```
(setq emacs-persistence-directory 
  (expand-file-name "var" user-emacs-directory))
(let ((dir (expand-file-name "backup" emacs-persistence-directory)))
  (unless (file-directory-p dir)
    (make-directory dir t))
  (setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,dir))))

(let ((backup-dir (concat emacs-persistence-directory "tramp-backup/")))
  (setq tramp-persistency-file-name (concat emacs-persistence-directory
                                            "tramp")
        tramp-backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,backup-dir))
        tramp-auto-save-directory (concat emacs-persistence-directory
                                          "tramp-auto-save/"))
  (dolist (d (list tramp-auto-save-directory backup-dir))
    (unless (file-exists-p d)
      (make-directory d t))))
```

---

Side note: auto-save is a different feature than backups.  Backups save a copy the first time you save a buffer (`C-x C-s`).  Above, I have the function `force-backup-of-buffer` on `before-save-hook` to backup on every save.  Autosave saves a copy every time you make a certain number of edits.  For a given file, there can be many backups, but there's only one autosave.

Comment: I am giving you credit for your answer, since it lead me to Chad Braunduin's Backups Mode   (https://github.com/chadbraunduin/backups-mode)  it seems this mode incorporates the backup Walker you point us to, plus more in an integrated package.  (I will write about it once I have experience with it.  THANKS!!)

Comment: @DanOblinger backups-mode looks promising, I'll check it out.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just in regard to the side note @jpkotta backups aren't saved everytime emacs saves a buffer. (At least since emacs 26.3) Their only saved the first time a buffer is written to file, and any subsequent saves do not affect the backup. You need to kill and then restart the buffer and then save it once more to create a new backup. (I just wrote a function to let me force emacs to write a new backup). See buffer-backed-up.

Comment: @MohsinKale true, I should have mentioned that it's the `force-backup-of-buffer` hook that makes it backup before saving.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving jpkotta's answer as the selected one, since backup-walker seems to work for others.  For my OSX box, I could not get Backup-Modes to work, and backup walker is more focused on DIFFS rather than just providing access to backup files.

Here is my hacked solution it is a kinda gross, but it works for me.
You will need to edit path names for your environment.
(see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups for the original)
I tried, Backup-Modes, and Backup-Directory https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory, but this is the first things that kinda worked.)

What this does:
- It fixes emacs so it *always* does an auto-save (surprisingly this is NOT the default)
- it adds the command   ``M-x history'' to open the backups directory.

Crude, but it works.  So sad to see Emacs die!

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;   FORCE-BACKUP-OF-BUFFER
;;;   (See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups)

(defun dao-setup-force-backup-of-buffer()
     (setq vc-make-backup-files t)          ; Do backups even for version controlled files!
     (setq version-control t                ; Use version numbers for backups.
      kept-new-versions 10                  ; Number of newest versions to keep.
      kept-old-versions 0                   ; Number of oldest versions to keep.
      delete-old-versions t                 ; Don't ask to delete excess backup versions.
      backup-by-copying t)                  ; Copy all files, don't rename them.
     (add-hook 'before-save-hook  'force-backup-of-buffer)
)

(defun force-backup-of-buffer ()
    ;; Make a special "per session" backup at the first save of each
    ;; emacs session.
    (when (not buffer-backed-up)
      ;; Override the default parameters for per-session backups.
      '(let ((backup-directory-alist  '(("." . "~/emacs-backups")))
            (kept-new-versions 3))
        (backup-buffer)))
      (backup-buffer)
    ;; Make a "per save" backup on each save.  The first save results in
    ;; both a per-session and a per-save backup, to keep the numbering
    ;; of per-save backups consistent.
    (let ((buffer-backed-up nil))
      (backup-buffer)))

(defun history ()
    (interactive)
    (dired-find-file "/User/oblinger/emacs-backups")
)
```